# How to get relevant equations for a force that does not act in a constant direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Have a look at this question, and the attached image file for the figure:

A uniform bar ABC has mass m and starts from rest with  = 180 degrees where A,B,C and O are collinear. If applied force P is constant in magnitude and always perpendicular to AC in the direction shown, determine the angular velocity  of the bar when =120 degrees. Apart from the bar, every other element is mass-less.

[image]

so my query is, how do i even start writing the equations?
had the force been acting in a constant direction i could have taken components and then solved them all but here the force changes directions every time!

Even if i write the equation for the force at some time, it will have changed direction the very next moment and my analysis will not hold at that moment!

Comment: To be honest I can't think how was the initial condition established! You said ABCO are colinear bot with that rod type hinge between O and C how is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56783/discussion-between-sakazuki-akainu-and-utkarsh-futous).